# Reduction of certain trigonometric functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

There is a trigonometric function: `Cos[m x]^2 Cos[n y]^2 Sin[m x] Sin[n y]`

I want to transform it to the next form:

```
1/16 Sin[m x] Sin[n y] + 1/16 Sin[3 m x] Sin[n y] + 1/16 Sin[m x] Sin[3 n y] + 1/16 Sin[3 m x] Sin[3 n y]
```

Here is what I do:

```
In:= Cos[m x]^2 Sin[m x] // TrigReduce      Out= 1/4 (Sin[m x] + Sin[3 m x])

In:= Cos[n y]^2 Sin[n y] // TrigReduce      Out= 1/4 (Sin[n y] + Sin[3 n y])

In:= 1/4 (Sin[m x] + Sin[3 m x]) 1/4 (Sin[n y] + Sin[3 n y]) // Expand
Out= 1/16 Sin[m x] Sin[n y] + 1/16 Sin[3 m x] Sin[n y] + 1/16 Sin[m x] Sin[3 n y] + 1/16 Sin[3 m x] Sin[3 n y]
```

I have amount of similar trigonometric functions to do the same transformation. So I want to ask If there any operations I can get the finial result in one step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
X = Cos[m x]^2 Cos[n y]^2 Sin[m x] Sin[n y];

TrigReduce[X] /. {Cos[a_ + b_] -> Cos[a] Cos[b] - Sin[a] Sin[b], 
                  Sin[a_ + b_] -> Cos[b] Sin[a] + Cos[a] Sin[b]} // Expand
```

> 1/16 Sin[m x] Sin[n y] + 1/16 Sin[3 m x] Sin[n y] + 1/16 Sin[m x] Sin[3 n y] + 1/16 Sin[3 m x] Sin[3 n y]